# What are the most commonly used open digital formats for chess games?

Tags: pgn

I have many of my old games in PGN format and a still quite many in paper format that I want to make digitally available.

I prefer make the digital versions in an open format that is widely used.

What are the most commonly used open digital formats for chess games?

Comment: Pgn is the most used.

Comment: PGN is so far out in front that it's hard to even think of an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most used is PGN.

You can arrange them in a database once you have enoguh PGNs to make it worth it. If you have money, ChessBase is great. If you want a free option there is SCID vs. PC (SCID for Linux)

Some links:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation
- http://shop.chessbase.com/en/products/chessbase12_download
- http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/
- http://scid.sourceforge.net/

Note :

SCID vs PC is better than the Windows version of SCID. My opinion of course.